# Accelerate: how do I add multiple vectors into an output vector of different size from the input vectors?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, vector, swift, accelerate-framework

I have four vectors, A,B,C,D, that are 1024 Doubles long. Then I have my output vector O, that is 1792 Doubles long, and initially is all zeros.

I want to add A into O so that A is added Double-for-Double at position 0-1023

I want to do the same for B 256 Doubles later, so add B into O so that B is added Double-for-Double at position 256-1279

Then the same for C, position 512-1535

Then finally the same for D, position 768-1791

How can I do this using Apple's Accellerate framework? I was looking into vDSP_vaddD, but the output array seems to have to be of the same length?

I'm trying to express this in Swift, if I were using Objective C I expect I could use pointer arithmetics to express where in the output array I wanted the start to be?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
O.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { (inout bufPtr : UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Double>) -> Void in
    var ptr = bufPtr.baseAddress
    vaddD(A, 1, ptr, 1, ptr, 1, 1024)
    ptr += 256
    vaddD(B, 1, ptr, 1, ptr, 1, 1024)
    ptr += 256
    vaddD(C, 1, ptr, 1, ptr, 1, 1024)
    ptr += 256
    vaddD(D, 1, ptr, 1, ptr, 1, 1024)
}
```

I admit that this looks ugly, and is unsafe in the sense that neither Swift compiler
nor the runtime can check the array bounds, but up to now that is the only solution
I could find.